# If I share a Minecraft seed with a friend, will this affect my world(as in 1.17 features)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a nice seed that I want to share with a friend. However, I would like to wait to explore a vast amount of the world until 1.17 comes out fully (I'm on Bedrock Edition, by the way). If my friend explores a lot of chunks, will those be preset on my world, e.g. if my friend explores eight chunks in his world before the update, and I don't, will those chunks not generate 1.17 features in my world, per se, copper? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A seed is just a way for Minecraft to tell itself how to generate the natural landscape. Your world and your friend's world are completely separate - they wouldn't even know each other existed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If a chunk is loaded in before an update, the update will **not** apply to those chunks.  Try and keep your friend from playing the world until the 1.17 update comes out - try making a new world and playing there until the update comes out.

Comment: When you say new world, will using the same seed affect another world with the same seed? I guess what I mean is if i use seed x, don't explore a chunk, however another person uses seed x, and does explore that chunk, on my world, will the chunk update to 1.17 on the chunk I have not loaded, although it wouldn't update on the other person's world?

Comment: No, I do not believe so.  However, we are not the programers for Mojang, and I couldn't say for 100% sure.  I am 95% sure that this is not the case, so I wouldn't worry.  If it does, then search up a seed similar to it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - it's a *separate* world.

Comment: This is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3):

No, your friend playing with the same seed will not affect future chunks on your world.

Answer (score 2):

Your friends playing on a seed will not effect your game. Seeds just create the world. If you play on the seed, it does not change it.